# compactness of a sequence space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, cauchy-sequences

Sorry if this  question might be not well-posed, I'm very very new to topology.
I have a compact set $S$ of sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and those sequences are bounded, in the sense that $S\subset l_\infty$.
I have a family of continuous functions $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ going from $S$ to $\mathbb R^d$.
For a given sequence $s\in S$ I can thus define the sequence $(y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb R^d$, where for any $k$, $y_k = f_k(s)$.
Moreover I know that $y_k=f_k(s)$ is bounded in the infinity norm for any sequence $s\in S$ and any $k\in\mathbb N$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} \|f_k(s)\|_\infty \le \bar a$ for a given finite constant $\bar a \in \mathbb R$. How can I conclude (if possible) that the set
$$
R := \left\{(f_k(s))_{k\in\mathbb N} \in l_\infty \,\mid\, s\in S \right\}
$$ 
is compact ?
I thought that maybe I can start showing that $R$ is bounded in the sense that any sequence $(f_k(s))_{k\in\mathbb N}\in R$ has a $l_\infty$ norm less or equal than a given constant and then show that any Cauchy sequence converges inside, however I'm quite confused about
thanks a lot

Comment: The image of a compact set under a continuous map is always compact.

Comment: do you mean that: since every $f_k$ is continuous then $F_k := f_k(Q)$ is compact, and since the set of the sequences $(f_k(s))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is in a bijection with $\prod_{k\in\mathbb N} F_k$ then it is compact in the product topology ?

Comment: So $f_{k} : \ell_{\infty} \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is continuous, so $f_{k}(S)$ is compact. If $R = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty} f_{k}(S)$, then it's a product of compact sets. It can also be shown that an arbitrary product of compact sets is compact. The strongest statement of this is Tychonoff's theorem, but Tychonoff's theorem is in general equivalent to the axiom of choice, but if you find that problematic I don't think you need AC to show this product is compact.